# How to get the edit history for an event in a Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have created a Google Calendar associated with a study group. The group is hosted using Google Groups and since the calendar is shared with the group, a member of the group can create and edit events on the calendar.

The size of the group will be about 20. To prevent unauthorized/anonymous changes to events made on the calendar, I was looking for a way to see the history of edits made to any given event in the calendar. I would also prefer to have a history of deleted events.

I can also go for an approach which uses the api. In fact, it might even be desirable, as I am writing a program for reserving some resources associated with the group using the Google Calendar API. However, I couldn't find any suitable command in the [command reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events), which would fetch me the history of edits to events on the calendar.

Is there a simple solution to this problem? If I make it known that edits are detectable, such vagrancies will be unlikely in a group of 20. But given the number, which will likely increase in the future, I don't want *trust* to be the sole mechanism for *checks & balances*.